# Conditional update of selectInput widgets

Tags: r, shiny

Using the `starwars` dataset, below is a minimal example of the issue I am facing.

My app has three `selectInput` for filtering out a datatable. These `selectInput` update each other depending on the selected value of the previous one.

The app also contains radio buttons for selecting type characters. When the radio button 'default' is clicked, the `selectInput` should select the first value among the choices by default. However, when a radio button is a character (i.e. not 'default'), the `selectInput` should update and select the value defining the character (through a reactive object `info()`).
As a consequence of the change in selection of the `selectInput`, the table should be filtered accordingly.

(The only constraint I have to follow here, is that I cannot use the dataset in the UI of the app.)

Here is the example app.

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId="sex",
                label="SEX",
                choices=c(""),
                selected=NULL
    ),
    selectInput(inputId="homeworld",
                label="HOMEWORLD",
                choices=c(""),
                selected=NULL
    ),
    selectInput(inputId="species",
                label="SPECIES",
                choices=c(""),
                selected=NULL
    ),
    hr(),
    radioButtons(inputId="radio",
                 label=NULL,
                 choices=c("default", "C-3PO", "Leia Organa")
    ),
    hr(),
    verbatimTextOutput("info_object"),
    hr(),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(session, input, output){
    
    # Get Sex / Homeworld / Species about character selected
    info <- reactive({
        if(input$radio == "default"){
            return(NULL)
        }
        else{
            list(Sex = starwars %>% subset(name == input$radio) %>% pull(sex),
                 Homeworld = starwars %>% subset(name == input$radio) %>% pull(homeworld),
                 Species = starwars %>% subset(name == input$radio) %>% pull(species))
        }
    })
    
    # To control the content of the 'info()' object
    output$info_object <- renderPrint({
        cat("info() object values:\n")
        print(info())
    })
    
    # Update selectInput widgets
    observe({
        if(is.null(info())){
            updateSelectInput(session=session,
                              inputId="sex",
                              choices=starwars$sex %>% 
                                         unique()
            )
            
            observeEvent(input$sex, {
                updateSelectInput(session=session,
                                  inputId="homeworld",
                                  choices=starwars %>% 
                                          subset(sex == input$sex) %>% 
                                          pull(homeworld) %>% 
                                          unique()
                )
            })
            
            observeEvent(input$homeworld, {
                updateSelectInput(session=session,
                                  inputId="species",
                                  choices=starwars %>% 
                                          subset(sex == input$sex & homeworld == input$homeworld) %>% 
                                          pull(species) %>% 
                                          unique()
                )
            })
        }
        else{
            updateSelectInput(session=session,
                              inputId="sex",
                              choices=starwars$sex %>% 
                                      unique(),
                              selected = info()$Sex
            )
            
            observeEvent(input$sex, {
                updateSelectInput(session=session,
                                  inputId="homeworld",
                                  choices=starwars %>% 
                                          subset(sex == input$sex) %>% 
                                          pull(homeworld) %>% 
                                          unique(),
                                  selected = info()$Homeworld
                )
            })
            
            observeEvent(input$homeworld, {
                updateSelectInput(session=session,
                                  inputId="species",
                                  choices=starwars %>% 
                                          subset(sex == input$sex & homeworld == input$homeworld) %>% 
                                          pull(species) %>% 
                                          unique(),
                                  selected = info()$Species
                )
            })
        }
        
        # Data table
        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(starwars %>% subset(sex == input$sex & homeworld == input$homeworld & species == input$species))
        })
    })                             
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see the `selectInput` do not update properly when choosing a radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to a conflict between your choices and and selected.

For this type of thing I like to build a reactive chain, but observing both selects will also work. Change your `observeEvent`(s) for species to:

```
  observeEvent(c(input$homeworld, input$species), {
    updateSelectInput(session=session,
                      inputId="species",
                      choices=starwars %>% 
                        subset(sex == input$sex & homeworld == input$homeworld) %>% 
                        pull(species) %>% 
                        unique(),
                      selected = info()$Species
    )
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for this example but not for my real app unfortunately. Just out of curiousity in case it could help me more, what do you mean by 'reactive chain'? What would it be for this example?

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit of a can-of-worms and it might not work here.  I was referring to making your inputs reactive (in the server). This way,  your homeworld input reacts to your sex input, and your species input reacts to your homeworld input (like a chain).